# activate a function (OnUpdate) for a specific parameter of a document in Firebase Functions

Tags: firebase, triggers, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I want to make a function that is activated when a parameter of the document is specific.
For example:
users/{idDoc}

```
Structure of users
              {
                idDoc:1,
                update:true
               },
              {
                idDoc:2,
                update:false
              }
```

When i write a function i define:

```
functions.firestore.document('users/{IdDoc}/}').onUpdate((change,context)=>{});
```

but what I need is for the function to be activated when the document is changed but also when update=false, is it possible to do this?

example:

```
onUpdate('users/{IdDoc}') && update==false
```

Thanks For your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Cloud Function will trigger for all updates of the given path. There is no option to only trigger on certain values within that path.

If you only want to trigger for user docs with update false, consider writing to a specific path (e.g. `/userDocsWithFalseUpdates`), so that you can filter the triggers on that. It's not ideal, but it's the only way to currently get the behavior you want.